# Why do we need a "muslim" tag?

Tags: discussion, tag

Title says it all: We have a [muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim) tag, but I can't fathom any constructive use for it; might as well just add [islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islam) to everything while we're at it (don't do that).

What possible use does this have?  Should it just be burninated?

Answer (score 3):

I went through all 49+15+21+20+1 = 106 questions tagged [muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim) ([search](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim)) and categorized them as follows:

Used as an irrelevant tag (46%): [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36907/17163) <strike>[2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38423/17163) [3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38315/17163) [4](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38058/17163)</strike><sup>(deleted)</sup>[5](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35243/17163) [6](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/34879/17163) [7](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33558/17163) [8](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33283/17163) [9](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32871/17163) [10](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32781/17163) [11](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32758/17163) [12](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32727/17163) [13](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31066/17163) [14](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30892/17163) [15](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30194/17163) [16](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29661/17163) [17](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29618/17163) [18](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29578/17163) [19](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29491/17163) [20](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29287/17163) [21](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/28545/17163) [22](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/28432/17163) [23](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/28034/17163) [24](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27906/17163) <strike>[25](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27905/17163)</strike><sup>(merged)</sup> [26](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27739/17163) [27](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/26359/17163)<sup>(please delete)</sup> [28](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/25033/17163) [29](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24662/17163) [30](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24084/17163) [31](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23842/17163) [32](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/21576/17163) [33](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/18481/17163) [34](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16604/17163) <strike>[35](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16405/17163)</strike><sup>(deleted)</sup> [36](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/14433/17163) [37](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11316/17163) [38](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10105/17163) [39](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9653/17163) [40](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9532/17163) [41](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8383/17163) [42](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5530/17163) <strike>[43](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2743/17163)</strike> [44](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2129/17163) [45](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1827/17163) <strike>[46](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1663/17163)</strike> [47](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1428/17163) [48](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1072/17163) [49](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38/17163).  The ones I wish to modify are below:

- These need editing: <strike>[6](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/34879/17163) [12](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32727/17163) [14](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30892/17163)</strike> <strike>[17](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29618/17163) [24](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27906/17163) [28](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/25033/17163)</strike> <strike>[34](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16604/17163)</strike> <strike>[39](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9653/17163) [40](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9532/17163) [44](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2129/17163)</strike>.  Done what needs to be done.

Used as a tangentially relevant tag (14%): <strike>[1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38109/17163)</strike> <strike>[2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/34922/17163)</strike><sup>(deleted)</sup> <strike>[3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29503/17163)</strike> [4](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23529/17163) [5](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/21463/17163) [6](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/18465/17163) <strike>[7](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17362/17163)</strike><sup>(deleted)</sup> [8](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17248/17163) <strike>[9](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16915/17163)</strike><sup>(deleted)</sup> <strike>[10](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10078/17163)</strike> [11](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9526/17163) [12](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8692/17163) [13](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5524/17163) [14](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1360/17163) [15](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/245/17163).  Done what needs to be done.

Used as a vaguely relevant tag (20%): <strike>[1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37962/17163) [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35620/17163) [3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30468/17163) [4](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29791/17163)</strike> <strike>[5](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29466/17163)<sup>(deleted)</sup> [6](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29461/17163) [7](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29342/17163)</strike> <strike>[8](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/28682/17163) [9](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24832/17163) [10](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/20303/17163) [11](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17606/17163)</strike> <strike>[12](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16877/17163) [13](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/14620/17163) [14](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10719/17163)</strike> <strike>[15](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9199/17163) [16](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5674/17163) [17](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5487/17163)</strike> <strike>[18](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5429/17163) [19](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5407/17163) [20](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1531/17163)</strike> [21](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/391/17163)<sup>(*confused*)</sup>.  Done what needs to be done.

Used as a relevant tag (19%): <strike>[1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36186/17163) [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30675/17163) [3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29629/17163) [4](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27902/17163) [5](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24536/17163) [6](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23719/17163) [7](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/18476/17163)</strike> <strike>[8](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17612/17163)</strike> <strike>[9](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17453/17163)</strike> <strike>[10](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17237/17163) [11](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11597/17163) [12](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11331/17163) [13](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11300/17163)</strike> <strike>[14](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8664/17163) [15](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8522/17163) [16](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5485/17163)</strike> <strike>[17](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2718/17163) [18](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/249/17163) [19](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/156/17163) [20](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/18/17163)</strike>  Gone.

Should be re-tagged [sahih-muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sahih-muslim): <strike>[1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9756/17163)</strike>

- New questions: [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38591/17163) [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39058/17163).

(Of course, there's some boundary cases, and all this is subjective.)

---

What I found:

- Often the tag was totally irrelevant.  In these cases, the question could use other repairs (in addition to removing the [muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim) tag), but this answer can be used for indexing them in the future.
- Many questions take the form "Is X halal?" but phrased as "Is X halal for Muslims?"
- Some questions are about Muslim demographics, behaviours and terminology.  There are (or we can create) better choices for tags, e.g.:

  - Demographics: [How many Muslims in the world are "moderate/progressive" and why are they called as such?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27902/17163)
  - Behaviour: [Why do Muslims attempt to convert Christians, Jews and Sabians to Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17237/17163)
  - Terminology: [What is a "Muslim" (surrendered) and what is a "Mumin" (believer/safe)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/18/17163)

---

What would I suggest:

- Yes, let's get rid of it; it's more trouble than it's worth.  But first...
- Let's go through the questions above listed as "vaguely relevant tags" and "relevant tags" and retag them appropriately.
- We should retag questions that have only the [muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim) tag.  (Or does burninating the tag from single-tag questions result in adding the [untagged](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag, and we can just fix that afterwards?)
- Some of these questions are closed and unanswered, and they probably can be deleted ([search](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmuslim%5D+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Atrue+answers%3A0)).

---

This is now complete.  I basically just edited them away one by one until there were no more.  See: [Can we zap the "muslim" tag now?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2940/17163)

Comment: I see you used your math here, nice haha!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the tag itself is on-topic, and even if it was, it is as you say "Too broad".  There are a number of tags like that by the way.  Bur the reason this one is off-topic is because this site is for questions about Islam, if a question is asked about Muslims it must be made so it is on-topic, like asking about an action, or a saying etc.  I support that the tag should be destroyed.

Answer (score -1):

The arguments against deleting it are strong.  However, if we can foresee a need for it when it needs to apply to general and transcending issues, maybe it can be replaced by something like `Islam-General`.

Comment: yes that may work, but you see, general questions or too broad questions aren't really good here, like the question "Who is God?" is too broad/general.  The question can be taken down a notch perhaps by asking "can God be known?", it can be made even more specific by asking "Is Annasir a name of God?" or by asking "Can we call God by attributes that He didn't describe Himself in?" .  So you see, here we want specific questions, specific questions get specific answers, if a question is too broad then the benefit of the answer goes down.  So we don't really like general questions here.