# Can we zap the "muslim" tag now?

Tags: feature-request, tag, burninate-request

In response to this question [Why do we need a "muslim" tag?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/679/17163), I proposed we get rid of the [muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim) tag.  The answer score is currently +3, and I've been editing questions in preparation for its removal.  To my knowledge, nobody has complained.

I think we're ready to get rid of it now.  **Can we burninate/blacklist this tag?**

**Update**: I've been editing it away bit by bit from the remaining questions.  Now [muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim) is only used for closed questions, which I'd prefer not to bump.

There is one question with only the tag [muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim): [I want to know to marry her or not](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27905/17163) has the single tag [muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim) but was merged and is now uneditable.

---

**Alternative tags**:

For future reference, consider using these alternatives:

- [demographics](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demographics)
- [terminology](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) or [definitions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definitions)
- [non-muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-muslim)
- [muslim-practices](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim-practices)
- [adab](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adab) which is currently defined as "Etiquette, morals, manners, and general good behaviour that all Muslims should strive for."
- [culture](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture)
- [behavior](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior)

---

In StackExchange tradition, I think I'm obligated to post this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim) is now (manually) burninated.

I can't blacklist it, which would prevent it from coming back; so please keep an eye out for it coming back.  It's unlikely to be used in any meaningful way: [Why do we need a "muslim" tag?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/679/17163).

[image]